# jQuery how to bind after unbind

Tags: jquery

I've a super simple id tag which has click event. I've used JQuery unbind to disable the click for certain scenarios and when I try to bind again with code below the click event never gets fired.

```
disableButton()
{
    $('#id1').unbind('click');
}
        .......
enableButton()
{
    $('#id1').bind('click');
}
```

Click handler looks like below:

```
$("#id1").click(function () {
    //apply some complex front end business rules
}
```

Could someone please help me with what I'm doing right/wrong?

I just want to enable or disable the click, is there easier way to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

From what I understand both bind and on requires a call back function which gets executed. This is going to be an issue for my case as I don't want to execute the click event but just enable the click event and ready for click to happen.

Isn't it possible to just to disable and enable click event without having to pass call back functions?

Comment: What code are you executing on click handler ?

Comment: click handler does lots of business logics on front end.Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

declare first the function:

```
function clickFunction(){
//your code here, to be execute on click
}
```

when you need it, bind the click function on the click-event

```
$('#id1' ).on("click", clickFunction())
```

and unbind with off later:

```
$('#id1' ).off("click", clickFunction())
```

when you want to bind it once again:  `$('#id1' ).on("click", clickFunction())`

Comment: Might want to fix the copy/paste typo...your 'off' example uses 'on'

Comment: hmm.... i just want to enable or disable the click event on this id and keep my business logic somwhere else.

Comment: I don't have function for click, I just have like this $("#id1").click(function () { .....}

Comment: yes but...its not so, that you define the function with $("#id1").click(function () { .....} and bind and unbind when you want. you have to define the function to be execute on click every time, it could be another function every time. i will edit my answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12638/discussion-between-dirty-flow-and-myagdi)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue with needing to unbind an on("click") and the only way I could get it to stop is by utilizing a switch on a counter I defined. Maybe this approach could be helpful.

```js
$(".images").on("click", function () {
    console.log(this.id);

    switch (cntr) {
       case 0:
           something();
           break;
       case 1:
           something();
           break;
       default:
           return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The given solution solved my problem, You should also try this.

```
$(function() {
    bindratings();
});

function bindratings() {
    var selector = $(".class_name");
    selector.bind("click", function() {
        selector.unbind("click");

        // write your code here

        setTimeout('bindratings();', 100);
    });
}
```